# Как перейти на одно окно назад(закрыть побочное окно)? PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Есть файлы, которые я предварительно создал в *Qt Designer*:

- Первый, главный - **menu.py**
- Второй, побочный - **maine.py**

С помощью функции `openent()` главное окно открывает побочное.
Также главное окно я не закрываю и не скрываю, соответственно новые окна открываются поверх старого.

Есть кнопка, которая закрывает выбранное окно(Кнопка назад). 
Когда я открываю через главное окно побочное, моя функция в побочном окне для его закрытия (`closew2`) не работает, пишет:

> Window2.close() 
> NameError: name 'Window2' is not defined

Если же я запускаю в *PyCharm* это окно отдельно, то все работает. Думаю проблема в вызове побочного окна, но не знаю, как исправить. Я новичок)))

Как пофиксить это?

Код главного файла:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import numpy as np
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton,
                             QToolTip, QMessageBox, QLabel)
import boxto

from maine import Ui_Window2
from keyboard_ent import Ui_Window3

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def openent(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_Window2()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
        self.window
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(609, 390)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 80, 71, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 151, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 80, 71, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 100, 151, 32))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        #открываем ввод кол-ва
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.openent)

        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 70, 201, 61))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 300, 101, 40))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 201, 61))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 609, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 171, 12))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.closew1)
        # открываем ввод переменных
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.openent)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загружен"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ввод из файла"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загружен"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Result"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ввод с клавиатуры"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вычислить"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выйти"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вывести данные из файла"))


    def closew1(self):
        MainWindow.close()





if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Код побочного:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import numpy as np
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton,
                             QToolTip, QMessageBox, QLabel)
import boxto

from keyboard_ent import Ui_Window3


class Ui_Window2(object):

    def setupUi(self, Window2):
        Window2.setObjectName("Window2")
        Window2.resize(751, 393)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Window2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 741, 131))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 260, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 260, 150, 32))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("font: 13pt \"Lucida Grande\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 20, 521, 51))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("font: 24pt \"Lucida Grande\";")
        self.label_3.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        Window2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Window2)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 751, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        Window2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Window2)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Window2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(Window2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Window2)
        #вызов вычисления и ввод значений
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.perent)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.closew2)
    def retranslateUi(self, Window2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Window2.setWindowTitle(_translate("Window2", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Window2", "Введите количество переменных"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Window2", "1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Window2", "2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Window2", "3"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Window2", "4"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Window2", "5"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Window2", "Введите количество ограничений"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("Window2", "1"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("Window2", "2"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("Window2", "3"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("Window2", "4"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(4, _translate("Window2", "5"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Window2", "Далее"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Window2", "Сохранить и выйти"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Window2", "ВВОД НАЧАЛЬНЫХ ПАРАМЕТРОВ"))


    def perent(self):
        boxto.var_count = self.comboBox.currentText()
        boxto.ogr_count = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_Window3()
        self.ui.checkp
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def closew2(self):
        boxto.var_count = self.comboBox.currentText()
        boxto.ogr_count = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
        Window2.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Window2()
    ui.setupUi(Window2)
    Window2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы предоставили не воспроизводимый пример,
поэтому я сделал - как понял.

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА!** 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета,
и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
import sys
#from scipy.optimize import linprog
#import numpy as np

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, 
    QPushButton, QToolTip, QMessageBox, QLabel)
    
# ???import boxto
# ???from keyboard_ent import Ui_Window3

#from maine import Ui_Window2
class Ui_Window2(object):
# Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer.
    def setupUi(self, Window2):
        Window2.setObjectName("Window2")
        Window2.resize(751, 393)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Window2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 741, 131))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 260, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 260, 150, 32))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("font: 13pt \"Lucida Grande\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 20, 521, 51))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("font: 24pt \"Lucida Grande\";")
        self.label_3.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        Window2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Window2)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 751, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        Window2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Window2)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Window2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(Window2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Window2)
        
# Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer.
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.perent)
#        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.closew2)
        
    def retranslateUi(self, Window2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Window2.setWindowTitle(_translate("Window2", "Window2"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Window2", "Введите количество переменных"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Window2", "1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Window2", "2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Window2", "3"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Window2", "4"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Window2", "5"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Window2", "Введите количество ограничений"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("Window2", "1"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("Window2", "2"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("Window2", "3"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("Window2", "4"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(4, _translate("Window2", "5"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Window2", "Далее"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Window2", "Сохранить и выйти"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Window2", "ВВОД НАЧАЛЬНЫХ ПАРАМЕТРОВ"))

# Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer.


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(609, 390)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 80, 71, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 151, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 80, 71, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 100, 151, 32))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

# Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer.
#        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.openent)

        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 70, 201, 61))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 300, 101, 40))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 201, 61))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 609, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 171, 12))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

# Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer.
#        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.closew1)
#        # открываем ввод переменных
#        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.openent)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загружен"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ввод из файла"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загружен"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Result"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ввод с клавиатуры"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вычислить"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выйти"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вывести данные из файла"))

# Это что-то типа boxto.py 
class Window3(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Window3")
        self.resize(200, 200)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.parent = parent

# ???        boxto.var_count = ???  f'var_count = {self.var_count}'
        self.var_count = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.ogr_count = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Назад')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked) 

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)                                          
        layout.addWidget(self.var_count)        
        layout.addWidget(self.ogr_count) 
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)         

    def onClicked(self):
        self.var_count.setText(
            f'var_count = {self.parent.window2.comboBox.currentText()}')
        self.ogr_count.setText(
            f'ogr_count = {self.parent.window2.comboBox_2.currentText()}') 
            
        self.parent.label_3.setText(
            f'Result: '
            f'var_count = {self.parent.window2.comboBox.currentText()}, '
            f'ogr_count = {self.parent.window2.comboBox_2.currentText()}'
        )
        self.parent.label_3.adjustSize()
        self.close() 
        self.parent.window2.close()        
    

class Window2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Window2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.parent = parent
        
        # вызов вычисления и ввод значений
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self._perent)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.closew2)        
        
    def _perent(self):
#        boxto.var_count = self.comboBox.currentText()
#        boxto.ogr_count = self.comboBox_2.currentText()

        self.parent.window3.var_count.setText(f'var_count = {self.comboBox.currentText()}')
        self.parent.window3.ogr_count.setText(f'ogr_count = {self.comboBox_2.currentText()}')
        self.parent.window3.show()

#        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#        self.ui = Ui_Window3()
#        self.ui.checkp
#        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
#        self.window.show()

    def closew2(self):
#        boxto.var_count = self.comboBox.currentText()
#        boxto.ogr_count = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
        self.parent.window3.var_count.setText(f'var_count = {self.comboBox.currentText()}')
        self.parent.window3.ogr_count.setText(f'ogr_count = {self.comboBox_2.currentText()}')

        self.parent.label_3.setText(
            f'Result: '
            f'var_count = {self.comboBox.currentText()}, '
            f'ogr_count = {self.comboBox_2.currentText()}'
        )
        self.parent.label_3.adjustSize()
        self.close()        
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)   

        # открываем ввод кол-ва
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.openent)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.closew1)

        self.window2 = Window2(self)
        self.window2.hide()
        
        self.window3 = Window3(self)
        self.window3.hide()

    def openent(self):
        self.window2.show()
#        self.hide()

    def closew1(self):
        self.close()        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ИгорьТолокнов  пожалуйста.