Прошу помочь с переходом между окнами на pyqt5 по кнопке
Я пытался искать у других людей, пытался через QDialog, но ситуации
похожей на мою, я не нашёл. Также другие программисты используют структуру сделанную qt designer, не предусматривая дальнейших изменений через qt designer. И всё же я думаю будет легче программировать визуал через отдельный класс.
Прошу показать на примере какого-нибудь мини-приложения.
win_main1.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QGridLayout, QWidget, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QSettings, QUrl
from info_micro import list_microphones
from os import path
from window1 import Ui_MainWindow
from info_micro import list_microphones
from win_main2 import Window2
from time import sleep
import webbrowser
import toml

press_btn = False
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #Наследование
        
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        #Импорт иконок:
        #TitleWin
        
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        parent_dir = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(path.join(parent_dir,"texture","icontitle.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)
        
        #Кнопка запуска ассистента
        
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(path.join(parent_dir,"texture","icon_play1.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.ui.btn_play.setIcon(icon1)
        self.ui.btn_play.setFlat(True)
        self.ui.btn_play.clicked.connect(self.start_ass)
        
        #Кнопка настроек
        
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(path.join(parent_dir,"texture","icon_settings.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.ui.btn_settings.setIcon(icon2)
        self.ui.btn_settings.setFlat(True)
        
        #buttons_settings
        
        self.ui.btn_settings.clicked.connect(self.new_window_event)
        
        #Галвный текст
        
        self.ui.title_text.linkActivated.connect(self.open_url)
        self.ui.title_text.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        
        
    def open_url(self):
        webbrowser.open_new('http:/vaskill.rf.gd')
        
    def new_window_event(self): 
        pass
        
    def start_ass(self):
        parent_dir = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
        global press_btn
        if press_btn == False:
            icon_play = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon_play.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(path.join(parent_dir, 'texture', 'icon_stop.png')))
            self.ui.btn_play.setIcon(icon_play)
            press_btn = True
            print(press_btn)
        elif press_btn == True:
            icon_play1 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon_play1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(path.join(parent_dir, 'texture', 'icon_play1.png')))
            self.ui.btn_play.setIcon(icon_play1)
            press_btn = False
            print(press_btn)
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


win_main2.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QGridLayout, QWidget, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QSettings
from info_micro import list_microphones
from os import path
from window2 import Ui_MainWindow
from info_micro import list_microphones
import toml


class Window2(QMainWindow, QDialog):
    
    
    
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #Наследование
        
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        global parent_dir
        parent_dir = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
        
        #Загрузка настроек
        
        with open(path.join(parent_dir, 'settings', 'config.ini'), 'r') as f:
            confs = toml.load(f)

        global config
        config = confs
        
        
        #Импорт иконок:
        #TitleIcon
        
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(path.join(parent_dir, "texture","icontitle.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)
        
        #Значения
        
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", path.join(parent_dir, 'models', 'small_model_ru')))
        
        #TitleText5
        
        self.ui.title_text_5.setText('Модель распознавания речи')
        
        
        #pushButton
        
        self.ui.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        
        #pushButton_2
        
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.dial)
        
        #textline_3
        
        self.ui.lineEdit_3.setText(config['name_bot'])
        
        info_mic = list_microphones()
        
        self.ui.comboBox.addItem(f'Нет')
        for i, mics in enumerate(info_mic):
                mi = mics.split()
                if mi[0] == 'Microphone':
                        self.ui.comboBox.addItem(f'{i}:{mics}')
                else :
                        mi[0] = 'Микрофон'
                        mi.pop(1)
                        self.ui.comboBox.addItem(f'{i}:{str(mics)}')
        #TabWidget
        self.ui.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        #comboBox
        self.ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.change_micro)
        self.ui.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(config['micro'])
        #comboBox2
        self.ui.comboBox_2.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.change_theme)
        self.ui.comboBox_2.setCurrentIndex(config['theme'])
        #pushbutton
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicks_used)
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.setText(config['model'])
        
    def change_micro(self, value):
        config['micro'] = value
        
    def change_theme(self, value):
        config['theme'] = value
        
    def clicks_used(self):
        config['name_bot'] = self.ui.lineEdit_3.text()
        print(config)
        with open(path.join(parent_dir, 'settings', 'config.ini'), 'w') as f:
            confs = toml.dump(config, f)
        
#Выбор категории
    def action_click(self):
        self.dial()  
    
    
    def dial(self):
            
        fname = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выберите путь до модели")
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.setText(str(fname))
        config['model'] = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        if fname == '':
                
                mess_box = QMessageBox()
                mess_box.setWindowTitle('Ошибка')
                mess_box.setText('Выберите модель!')
                mess_box.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
                mess_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
                mess_box.buttonClicked.connect(self.action_click)
                
                mess_box.exec_()
                
                
                
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window2()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


window1.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'window1.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.11
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 500)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 500))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 500))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../texture/icontitle.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: \'black\';\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 480, 111, 16))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777212, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.title_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.title_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 20, 201, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bulatov SP Demo")
        font.setPointSize(50)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.title_text.setFont(font)
        self.title_text.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.title_text.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.title_text.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.title_text.setStyleSheet("@font-face {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 0, 4);\n"
"    font-family: \"Bulatov\"; \n"
"    src: url(\"C:/VASKILL/fonts/BulatovSPDemo.otf\") format(\"truetype\"); \n"
"    font-style: normal; \n"
"    font-weight: normal; \n"
"  } \n"
"\n"
"#title_text{\n"
"    font: 50pt \"Bulatov SP Demo\";\n"
"    color:\'red\';\n"
"    font-style: italic;\n"
"}")
        self.title_text.setObjectName("title_text")
        self.btn_play = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_play.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 260, 81, 81))
        self.btn_play.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btn_play.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"border: 1px solid \'black\';\n"
"border-radius:15px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    \n"
"    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.btn_play.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("texture/icon_play1.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_play.setIcon(icon1)
        self.btn_play.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 90))
        self.btn_play.setFlat(True)
        self.btn_play.setObjectName("btn_play")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 400, 231, 41))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 12pt \"Segoe Fluent Icons\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 370, 371, 41))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 12pt \"Segoe Fluent Icons\";")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.btn_settings = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_settings.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 10, 31, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.btn_settings.setFont(font)
        self.btn_settings.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btn_settings.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.btn_settings.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 1px solid \'black\';\n"
"border-radius:15px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btn_settings.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("texture/icon_settings.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_settings.setIcon(icon2)
        self.btn_settings.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.btn_settings.setCheckable(False)
        self.btn_settings.setFlat(True)
        self.btn_settings.setObjectName("btn_settings")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "SKILL"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "beta-v-0.0.1-design"))
        self.title_text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SKILL"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Если вы ещё этого не сделали."))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Просьба ознакомиться с настройками ассистента!"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



window2.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'window2.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.11
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 500)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 500))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 500))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../texture/icontitle.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: \'black\';")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.title_text_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.title_text_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 30, 201, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bulatov SP Demo")
        font.setPointSize(32)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.title_text_2.setFont(font)
        self.title_text_2.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.title_text_2.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.title_text_2.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.title_text_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.title_text_2.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.title_text_2.setObjectName("title_text_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 440, 381, 51))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    font: 23pt \"Bulatov SP Demo\";\n"
"    border: 1px solid \'black\';\n"
"    border-radius:10px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    \n"
"    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 381, 341))
        self.tabWidget.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bulatov SP Demo")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.tabWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tabWidget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.TabFocus)
        self.tabWidget.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.tabWidget.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.tabWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.tabWidget.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.North)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.title_text_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.title_text_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 0, 111, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.title_text_4.setFont(font)
        self.title_text_4.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.title_text_4.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.title_text_4.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.title_text_4.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.title_text_4.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.title_text_4.setObjectName("title_text_4")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 341, 41))
        self.comboBox.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_2.setEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 291, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.lineEdit_2.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setFrame(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.title_text_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.title_text_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 90, 200, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.title_text_5.setFont(font)
        self.title_text_5.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.title_text_5.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.title_text_5.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.title_text_5.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.title_text_5.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.title_text_5.setObjectName("title_text_5")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 120, 31, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border:4px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.title_text_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.title_text_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 170, 171, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.title_text_6.setFont(font)
        self.title_text_6.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.title_text_6.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.title_text_6.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.title_text_6.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.title_text_6.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        self.title_text_6.setObjectName("title_text_6")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 341, 41))
        self.comboBox_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.comboBox_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.title_text_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.title_text_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 91, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.title_text_7.setFont(font)
        self.title_text_7.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.title_text_7.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.title_text_7.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.title_text_7.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.title_text_7.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.title_text_7.setObjectName("title_text_7")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.title_text_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.title_text_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 20, 181, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.title_text_8.setFont(font)
        self.title_text_8.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.title_text_8.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.title_text_8.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.title_text_8.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.title_text_8.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.title_text_8.setObjectName("title_text_8")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEdit_3.setEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 351, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.lineEdit_3.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor))
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.lineEdit_3.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit_3.setFrame(True)
        self.lineEdit_3.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.title_text_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.title_text_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 100, 91, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.title_text_9.setFont(font)
        self.title_text_9.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.title_text_9.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.title_text_9.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.title_text_9.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.title_text_9.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.title_text_9.setObjectName("title_text_9")
        self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_3)
        self.comboBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 341, 41))
        self.comboBox_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.comboBox_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "SKILL-SETTINGS"))
        self.title_text_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "settings"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Применить"))
        self.title_text_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Микрофон"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "C:/VASKILL/models/small_model_ru"))
        self.title_text_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "       Модель"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.title_text_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<a href=\'https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models\'>Ссылка на сайт с моделями</a>"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Ассистент"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Dark"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Light"))
        self.title_text_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "       тема"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Тема"))
        self.title_text_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите имя для ассистента"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SkillBot"))
        self.title_text_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "     Голос"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Косметика ассистента"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())




Опишите пожалуйста подробнее, что вы хотите получить, в каком месте и как.

LooooZ, на самом деле похожих вопросов много, вот например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513050 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1357586 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1506431 и т.д.

@S.Nick спасибо огромное, я покопаюсь в этих трёх примерах поподробнее.
